# How to convert element nested children to Multi-dimensional associative arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

This is my menu layout in `html`

```
<ul>
    <li>1
        <ul>
            <li>1-1</li>
            <li>1-2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3
        <ul>
            <li>3-1
                <ul>
                    <li>3-1-1</li>
                    <li>3-1-2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>3-2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

How to convert this layout to Multi-dimensional associative JS array and keep items values ?

Comment: You need to programmically convert this?  Or is this a one-time conversion?

Comment: I need to convert it with both of them

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Do you mean into json?

Comment: yes Sam, I want convert it to json.

Answer (score 2):

To do this with a custom function, first you'd need code that gets the top ul, and iterates through all children.  I wrote some sample code for this here, if it's useful:

[getElementById doesn't work on a node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902671/getelementbyid-doesnt-work-on-a-node)

Then, when building a data structure, use these rules:

```
1. ul maps to a []
2. li maps to { "text value of li": children }
3. if there are no children, children is null
```