# Clarification on getElementById

Tags: javascript, dom

So I know that `getElementById` is available with the document object.

```
const ELEMENT_BY_ID = document.getElementById('header'); // works fine
```

Now what I am trying to do is to use `getElementById` on an HTML node instead of the document object.

```
const PARENT_ELEMENT = document.getElementById('parent');
const CHILD_BY_CLASS_NAME = PARENT_ELEMENT.getElementsByClassName('ch'); // Works fine
const CHILD_BY_ID = PARENT_ELEMENT.getElementById('child1'); // Error PARENT_ELEMENT.getElementById is not a function
```

Here with `PARENT_ELEMENT` I am able to use `getElementsByClassName` or Tag Name but don't know why `getElementById` is not available here. Is there a reason why `getElementsByClassName` is available but `getElementById` is not available? Below is my HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <span id="child1" class="ch ch1">Child</span>
    <span id="child2" class="ch ch3">Child</span>
    <span id="child3" class="ch ch3">Child</span>
</div>
```

Comment: getElementById() is a method which works only on **document**. Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById (it is written in the first paragraph)

Comment: Your affirmation  _"So I know that getElementById is available with the document object."_  should be _getElementById() works only with Document as stated in documentation_".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902671/getelementbyid-doesnt-work-on-a-node

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chaining getElementById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683087/chaining-getelementbyid)

Answer (score 4):

[**`getElementById()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) **Usage notes**

> Unlike some other element-lookup methods such as [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorall), `getElementById()` *is only available as a method of the global **document** object,* and not available as a method on all element objects in the DOM. Because ID values must be unique throughout the entire document, there is no need for "local" versions of the function.

Comment: Ok. Got It. Thanks

Comment: @SoumyajeetNayak, you are most welcome:)

Answer (score 2):

That's just how things are - `getElementById` only exists on the document (and on DocumentFragments - both implement the `NonElementParentNode` interface that has `getElementById`), as you can see in the DOM standard [here](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nonelementparentnode).

`getElementsByClassName`, on the other hand, can be called on either a document *or* an element, as you can see at the bottom of [this section](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-document) on the same page (search for: `collection = document . getElementsByClassName(classNames)`)

Comment: Ok. Got It. Thanks. I was just curious

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion is in that you are nesting a reference to an element ID. ID's are unique to each element, regardless of how they're nested in the DOM. So you can reference an element inside another element directly ...

```
<parent id='one'>
    <child id='two'></child>
</parent>
```

You don't need to access the child by referring to it's place in the parent, like `var el = getElementById('one').getElementById('two')`. You just reference it directly `var el = getElementById('two')`.

In contrast, many elements can have the same class, so you can get all of the elements of a class within a parent of a particular ID. `getElementsByClassName()` it iterative. `getElementById()` is not.

Comment: Chaining id doesn't make sense. We can directly get an id. Now that makes sense. Thanks